# Connecting to cqlsh from remote fails, where as from localhost it connects?

Tags: cassandra

Installed DSE on CentOS7 and saw no errors, I'm able to connect to cqlsh from the local machine and and I'm able to also do a telnet on the port.
However the problem is that when the same is done from a remote machine I get the below error
 cqlsh XX.XXX.XX.XX 3389
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'10.223.61.49': ConnectionShutdown('Connection to 10.223.61.49 was closed',)})

To check the connectivity I did a telnet on this and see the below error
telnet XX.XXX.XX.XX 3389
Invalid or unsupported protocol version (13); supported versions are (3/v3, 4/v4, 5/v5-beta, 65/dse-v1)

I tried updating the Python version, also few tweaks to change the py script also didn't help

Comment: Why are you using port 3389? The cassandra native transport port is 9042. You should be able to connect remotely to the server by running `cqlsh XX.XXX.XX.XX` without a port as long as you have not modified the default port in your cassandra.yaml.

Comment: Something else to remember, the database will listen to for native transport on the `native_transport_address` as configured in the yaml. If you set this to a private IP (say in AWS) you may have problems connecting to it from outside the subnet. What are your, listen, native_transport, and broadcast addresses set to?

Comment: I've updated native_transport_port: 3389 in cassandra.yaml as I have certain restrictions and also as mentioned when I do cqlsh XX.XXX.XX.XX 3389 I get connected, the issue is when I do the same from a remote box, though telnet XX.XXX.XX.XX 3389 on the same box works but gives an error as "Invalid or unsupported protocol version (13); supported versions are (3/v3, 4/v4, 5/v5-beta, 65/dse-v1)"